# Pixel to point for screen designing

Tags: ios, autolayout, storyboard, interface-builder

Hold on, I know there is a ton of info on this already, but I find it very confusing and it's doesn't work(in my case). I have a designer who sent me a PDF of a screen design for an application, designed for iPhone 6s. The spacing in that PDF is given in pixels. I have already gone through the [The Ultimate Guide To iPhone Resolutions](https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions), which almost everyone refers to. According to this article, I should convert the pixels in my PDF to point by dividing it by 2, since the iPhone 6S is rendered at 2x. However, when I do this and run my app in simulator it is nowhere close to what it looks in the PDF. Another thing that confused me is this article [here](https://www.createful.com/2014/designing-new-iphone-screen-resolutions/), which says 1 point on the iPhone 6 is 4 pixels. So if I divide the values in my PDF by 4, it still doesn't look perfect. What am I doing wrong here? How do I convert the given pixels to points to use in XCode.

**PDF**

[image]

Comment: Your pixel conversion from pdf will only make sense if it has been designed with that resolution in mind. Moreover you don't need to bother how many pixels are there behind a single point. Design your layout in points and leave the conversion to the system.

Comment: On relying solely on calculations I compare my views in storyboards with the actual designs and make adjustments if doesn't seem right.

Comment: @HAK: Yes, but then I need to know that right? Otherwise, how will I convert the pixels from the PDF to get the point value I need to layout my views?

Comment: 6 is 2x, 6Plus is 3x. You need to divide your pixels by 2 for 6, or 3 for 6Plus.

Comment: @HAK: Doing that my UI does not look like the one in PDF file, does that mean the designer messed  up the values?

Comment: @TejasK That might be the reason. Please share your PDF for further clarification.

Comment: @HAK: On the first page it says "GUIDELINES_V15_iOS_6, 6s, 7, 8_@2x (750x1334 at 326dpi)"

Comment: This is the overall dimension of iPhone 6, 6S, 7 or 8 screens. Dividing it by 2 gives the width and height of your screen in points i.e. (375x667).

Comment: @TejasK What is the exact resolution of the PDF (not what it says on the title). How are you measuring distances in your PDF?

Comment: @AshleyMills: I divide the values given in pixel by 2, but when I set the result to my views in IB, the output is not as it looks in the PDF.

Comment: This probably isn't solvable without seeing the PDF - or at least a single page of it

Comment: @AshleyMills: Check this Screenshot from the PDF, https://ibb.co/kzO7y8, here the 'Congratulations' label is said to be 180px from the navigation bar. How do I convert that to point, dividing by 2 doesn't make it look like the one in the screenshot.

Comment: @TejasK OK - so your label should be 90 points from the nav bar. Can you please add screenshot of your app to your question showing what it looks like?

Comment: @AshleyMills: https://ibb.co/esE2WT, the navigation bar ends at 64, so I did 64+90=154 and set the label's y position to 154 from the top. But if you compare both the images side by side, mine looks a bit downwards compared to the PDF.

Comment: Assuming the nav bar is 64 pt is a _really_ bad idea. What about when there's a double size status bar (during a phone call)? What about on the iPhone X? But see my answer for why it's in the wrong place normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PDF in the screenshot is 350px high

The spacing marked *180px* is approx 41px high

41/350 = 0.1171 of the height of the screen

0.1171 * 1134 = 132, *NOT* 180 - so it looks like the PDF isn't to scale

Comment: So the PDF isn't how it actually should be and I have to calculate all values just like you mentioned, right?

Comment: You should go and speak to the designer and ask them for a new PDF - explain to them that you need the size of the image to match the sizes written on the document

Answer (score 0):

You must divide your UIKit Component resolution by two. for example if you have some image of resolution 100x100. your UIImageView should be 50x50 point. it means in your each point there will be 4 pixels.

```
100 * 100 = 10_000 pixels
50 * 50 * 4 = 10_000 pixels
```

in Assets folder there should be 3 resolution:

```
1x = 50 x 50
2x = 100 x 100
3x = 150 x 150
```

Because your design resolution is iPhone 6s which uses 2x folder.

I hope it will be helpful for you.

Comment: But then like I said if I divide the Y position on a view from the PDF by dividing it by 2, it does not look like it is in the PDF.

Comment: Your pdf resolution is 750x1334 right? and your storyboard ViewController size is 375x667 right?  it should be same... :))